# how to use each loop of jquery data which comes on consol.log(data)

Tags: jquery

this is my code in which i have to apply for loop in data . thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      d3.csv(("../Files/" + $('#Label2').text()),function (data) {

          console.log(data);

          //console.log($("#Label2").text());
       })
 });
```

Comment: does your `data` hold simple one level object or its a complex structure having object holding another object kind of structure. Please share the structure of `data`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parseJSON to parse the data. Then only you can use the parsed object for looping.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      d3.csv(("../Files/" + $('#Label2').text()),function (data) {
              console.log(data);
          // parsing data 
          var parsedobj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          // now use this parsedobj for looping
       })
 });
```

Comment: but arun when try put data in loop and and than i try to post data to some url then its not working here is updated code

Comment: inside each don't use 'console.log(data[i])', Instead of that try 'console.log(i)' or 'console.log(item)' based on your requirement.